# Optimization of tag searching in XML file

Tags: c++, c, search

I'm writing custom function for getting all tags in an XML file. I'm using this code:

```
wchar_t *GetLine(wchar_t *fileName=L"indexing.xml", wchar_t endSymbol = '\n')
{
    SetFilePointer(hReadFile,sizeof(wchar_t) * position, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    int size;
    wchar_t wchr[1];
    DWORD dw;
    size = 0;
    do
    {
        ReadFile(hReadFile, wchr, sizeof(wchar_t), &dw, NULL);
        if(!dw)
        {
            break;
        }
        tempGetLine[size] = wchr[0];
        size++;
    }while(wchr[0] != endSymbol);
    tempGetLine[size] = '\0';
    position += (size);
    return tempGetLine;
}
wchar_t *GetTag(wchar_t *fileName = L"indexing.xml")
{
    wchar_t *temp = GetLine(fileName,'>');
    int i = 0;
    while(*temp != '\0')
    {
        tempTag[i] = *temp;
        i++;
        temp++;
    }
    tempTag[i] = '\0';
    return tempTag;
}
```

It works, but in a large file it takes a lot of iterations. How can I optimize my code?

Comment: Why are you passing the filename to `GetLine()` when it doesn't do anything with it?  It just uses `hReadFile`, which is presumably a global variable containing an already-opened filehandle.

Comment: @j_random_hacker you are right, my fault, but it have no relationship with make code faster

Comment: Have you considered moving to a true XML parser. For raw speed, SAX parsers are really good, and otherwise there are some lightweight DOM parsers that are quite easy to work with (I personally recommend [ticpp](http://code.google.com/p/ticpp/))

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider moving to a propper parser generator.

A good C++ library for such a task is boost spirit-qi, there is even an XML example.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html

[xml example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling `SetFilePointer()` for *every single tag*.  If you aren't doing any other reads or writes to the file in between calls to `GetTag()`, don't bother calling `SetFilePointer()` at all.  It's unnecessary, and it's possible that this call is reducing the amount of buffering done by the OS.

Comment: It may be that `ReadFile()` is incurring a kernel transition for every single character.  Normally people use `fopen()` and `fgetc()` to read from files, instead of the OS-supplied functions -- this has the twin benefits of (a) portability and (b) the buffering occurs *in user space*, meaning individual characters can be read efficiently.

Comment: you are right ReadFile() is incurring a kernel transition for every invoke. Does it mean that WriteFile() have the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, each call to `WriteFile()` will require a kernel transition as well.